# Nginx "No such file or directory error" for existing file path with appropriate permissions

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

When attempting to view the HLS stream being sent from OBS to Nginx, I keep getting the error:

`33 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/HLS/live/5cc56be78cea0.m3u8" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

but the path `/usr/share/nginx/html/HLS/live/` DOES exist (the stream file is also created) and I double checked the folder permissions

My Nginx config server block is:

```
server {

    listen 444 ssl;
    listen [::]:444 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/concartcert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;                    

    server_name 129.567.55.36;

    location /live {
        # Disable cache
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
        }
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/HLS/live;
    }
    # allows us to see how stats on viewers on our Nginx site using a URL like: "http://my-ip/stats"     
    # location /stats {
        # stub_status;
    # }
    location /stat {
        rtmp_stat all;
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
    }
    location /stat.xsl {
        root html;
    }
    location /control {
        rtmp_control all;
    }
    # allows us to host some webpages which can show our videos: "http://my-ip/my-page.html"     
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }   
}
```

Could anyone help my identify the possible cause of the error. Checking online, the two possible causes identified were the folder permissions or the folder path but after checking both I am lost on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use root in the server block instead of in the location blocks and then a try_files in the location blocks, like this:

```
    server {

            listen 444 ssl;
            listen [::]:444 ssl;

            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/concartcert.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;                    

            server_name 129.567.55.36;

            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;

            location /live {
                    # Disable cache
                    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

                    # CORS setup
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

                    # allow CORS preflight requests
                    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                            return 204;
                    }
                    types {
                            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                    }
                    try_files /HLS/live/$uri =404
            }
            #allows us to see how stats on viewers on our Nginx site using a URL like: "http://my-ip/stats"     
            #location /stats {
            #        stub_status;
            #}
            location /stat {
                    rtmp_stat all;
                    rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
            }
            location /control {
                    rtmp_control all;
            }
            #allows us to host some webpages which can show our videos: "http://my-ip/my-page.html"     
            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }   
    }
```

If the /stat and /control URLs don't work anymore because they have another root path, you should use `alias` with the full path in those location blocks.

Comment: Thanks @gidomanders. made the recommended changes. stat and control URLs still works though now getting the error : hls: cleanup stat() "/usr/share/nginx/html/HLS/live/5cc56be78cea0/4.ts" failed (13: Permission denied)